# stm32 writing to rw register has no effect

Tags: assembly, embedded, stm32

Tried to write a new value (0x00008000, set TSVREFE bit) to ADC control register 2 (ADC_CR2). No effect. I see unchanged value (0x00000000 after reset) in memory (address 0x40012408).
Should I configure something to be able to write to this register?

To test I tried this experimental routine:

```
__main      PROC
    EXPORT  __main
    LDR     R0, =ADC1_ADDR
    ADD     R0, #ADC_CR2_OFFSET
    MOV     R1, #0x00008000
    STR     R1, [R0]
    B   .
        
    ENDP

ADC1_ADDR               EQU 0x40012400
ADC_CR2_OFFSET          EQU 0x08

    END
```

Memory window looks like this after execution (breakpoint on B . line)

```
0x40012400 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x40012410 ...
```

Comment: Have you enabled the clock for the ADC peripheral? If not, you won't be able to write (or read) its registers.

Comment: As noted in the answer and comment, you have not enabled the ADC peripheral clock.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot write to any peripheral register if it's peripheral clock is not yet enabled in the RCC.

Be aware also that the GPIO clock for any I/O pins used by the peripheral must also be enabled before you can configure its alternate peripheral function.

All register values reading zero is normally a good indication that the clock is not enabled; for most peripherals the reset state for at least some registers is non-zero.